# VirtualBox RTR3InitEx failed with rc=-1912 error when trying to start a virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox

When trying to start a VM in VirtualBox VirtualBox (6.1.32) on host Ubuntu (20.04.4 LTS), I get an error message:

```
RTR3InitEx failed with rc=-1912 (rc=-1912)

The VirtualBox kernel modules do not match this version of VirtualBox. The installation of VirtualBox was apparently not successful. Executing

'/sbin/vboxconfig'

may correct this. Make sure that you are not mixing builds of VirtualBox from different sources.

where: supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime what: 4 VERR_VM_DRIVER_VERSION_MISMATCH (-1912) - The installed support driver doesn't match the version of the user.
```

I ran `sudo vboxconfig` and got:

```
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
```

Unfortunately this did not fix the problem. I rebooted the PC, which didn't fix it either.

Not sure if it's relevant, but I noticed the problem started occuring immediately after I did a Ubuntu update.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you install which Virtualbox version in which Ubuntu host release version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling and reinstalling VirtualBox fixed the issue.

```
$ sudo apt remove --purge virtualbox
$ sudo apt install virtualbox
$ sudo apt install virtualbox-dkms
```

Comment: Note, the latest operational version of VirtualBox for Ubuntu 20.04 Focal until today is 6.1 and the best way to install is with `apt` shown above. The latest version 7.0 which is available on the VirtualBox website is not working.